# How to modify the category of an issue already created in MANTIS?

Tags: edit, categories, mantis, bug-tracker

Users created some issues, but assigned a wrong category. I (admin) would like to fix this. How can I do this? Once an issue has been created the main fields seem to be unmodifiable.

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Found out by myself in the meantime. I was trying to edit it after clicking on the issue. This is not possible obviously. In the overview it is necessary to click on the "edit" icon of the related issue. Then any field can be modified.